# read txt by line and separate via commas in C++

Tags: c++, readfile

I have to read a .txt file line by line and separate the contents of each line with a comma so I  can create an object with each line. the Issue is, I've found out how to read each line and how to separate contents with a character( comma,dot,line,etc..) the problem is when I try to implement one with the other, everything crashes.

The end result should be that if in a text I have, for example:

```
135875,John,Smith
460974,Jane,Doe
```

I read each line and crate a linked list with objects containing the info of each person, so after reading each line I can call the constructor with the data extracted from the .txt

```
user(int ID,String Name,String LastName);
```

Comment: I think you need to show us the code that crashes.

Comment: Write down, using plain English, a logical process by which you expect to accomplish this. If you can't come up with a logical process for this, the issue is not C++, but a lack of logical, computation theory, and computer science skills. But if you can write down your proposed algorith, and [your rubber duck agrees with you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), then simply take what you have written down, and it should be directly translatable to C++ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show your code so I can't know what's wrong with your code. But here is a code snippet to read a file and do the things you need to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream ifs("test.txt");
    string line;
    while (getline(ifs, line))
    {
        istringstream iss(line);
        int id;
        string tmp,name,lastname;
        getline(iss, tmp, ',');
        // stoi is only supported in c++11
        // Alternatively, you can use id = atoi(tmp.c_str());
        id = stoi(tmp);
        getline(iss, tmp, ',');
        name = tmp;
        getline(iss, tmp, ',');
        lastname = tmp;
        cout << "id: " << id << endl;
        cout << "name: " << name << endl;
        cout << "lastname: " << lastname << endl;
    }
    ifs.close();
    return 0;
}
```